# Android emulator doesn't do anything?

Tags: android

I've just started playing around with android sample apps. For some reason, the emulator doesn't do anything. All I get is a black screen with with word "Android" and it stays like that until it crashes.

I'm not sure what the issue is but any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: not enough information to answer....

Comment: Emulator is one of the slowest thing on earth that you will ever encountered. How long have you been waiting?  Tell us the setting of your virtual device  please. Moreover, please note that it is very possible that you may have to reinstall the SDK.  All you need is anything related to 2.3.3 SO that saves time. As a beginner you dont need anything below 2.3.3 or anything above 2.3.3

Comment: @JohnWong: Not good advice. An AVD for v1.6 (for example) will load a lot quicker and use less resources than for v2.3.x. The OP says they've "just started playing with android sample apps". In many cases creating an AVD for v1.6 will allow experimenting with many of the code samples.

Comment: Also, seeing as hardly anyone has 2.3.3, it's an odd choice of target.

Comment: @MisterSquonk  you are right. Certinaly 1.6 loads much faster. I simply said that because many beginner like myself would just download everything and we hear "resintall the SDK!!!" we sigh because some of us have bandwidth problem. 2.3.3 is probably the most stable latest? i recommend it because if you just want to play and learn, starting the stable one isn't a bad choice. i run programs in 1.6 too.

Comment: Really guys? How about looking at the answer and stop bickering about Whig sdk he should use. I say let him get his question answered and let him get on with learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have got there is a bad system image on your emulator. Go to the AVD screen in eclipse(looks like a little android with a down arrow. Select the emulator that crashes but don't start it. Click delete instead. Then create a new one emulator with whatever sdk and options that you want. Should work after that.